# What's the purpose of a CSS Loader

Tags: angular, css-loader

I am playing with Angular2 at the moment. I am quite beginner in the web and all javascript world since I was mostly back-end .Net developper. I'm kind of confused with all the choices we have as javascript librairies that seems to do almost the same things differently with some noticeable differences.

In my case, I'm wondering what is the purpose of a CSS loader in an ng2 component when you can use the styleUrls property of a component.

I'm following this tutorial http://teropa.info/blog/2016/02/28/metabubbles-generative-art-with-angular-2.html#extracting-a-circles-service but I'm trying to reproduce it using typescript instead.

In the "Styling The Components with CSS" part, they're using Webpack's CSS Loader as following

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mb-canvas',
  template: `...`,
  styles: [require('css!./canvas.component.css').toString()],
  directives: [CircleComponent]
})
```

For now, as far as I know, it seems useless as we can use the styleUrls property of a component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mb-canvas',
  template: `...`,
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.css'],
  directives: [CircleComponent]
})
```

Can anyone help me understand ?
If it's a good practice to use a CSS Loader, since I'm using SystemJS, I don't think there is any support to load CSS files, should I switch to webpack or any of the multiple loader I find. It's really overpopulated with loader since each time I'm looking at exemples, I find another loader ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed some things here:

1. [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) is a Webpack feature, for loading css files using 'require' syntax. If you use Webpack, it is nice to use this in order to load you external css files using 'require'. You can even change the css into a string and add it to 'styles' array.
2. styleUrls is Angular 2 feature (it is a property of Angular's Component decorator. As you can see [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/25/styling-angular-2-components.html) ), It will be written to the head of the document.

So, it seems that the results are similar, used in a different way with different tools.

**EDIT**

So, the advantages of using 'require' with webpack are:

- You don't have to pack each style file
- You don't have to deploy all style files
- You don't have to do an extra http request for each style file
- You don't have to do hacks to make the url point to the cdn and not web page source

Comment: I can understand that, it's two different ways of doing a similar thing, using require or not, the question, actually, is what's the purpose of doing it with require(webpack)? Is there any advantages? Why should I do this and add another depency to the whole bunch of depencies of a project when there is already a built in way of doing it?